# Angular object property value change not propagated into view using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate a table using ng-repeat.

### Use case

The data to generate the table from looks as follows:

```
$scope.data = [
    {  
        name : 'foo1',  
        group : 1
    },
    {  
        name : 'foo2',  
        group : 1
    },
    {  
        name : 'foo3',  
        group : 1
    },
    {  
        name : 'foo4',  
        group : 1
    },
    {  
        name : 'foobar',  
        group : 2
    },
    {  
        name : 'foobarbar',  
        group : 3
    }
];
```

The html generated should look like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4">1</td>
    <td>foo1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1">2</td>
    <td>foobar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1">2</td>
    <td>foobarbar</td>
</tr>
```

---

### Implementation

I know the easiest way would probably be to pre-process the data and group the items per group in a new array of arrays. However, I chose a different approach:

```
<td
    ng-if   = "isDifferentFromPrev(items, $index, groupingData)"
    rowspan = "{{item._groupSize}}"
>
```

with

```
$scope.isDifferentFromPrev = function(array, index, groupingData){

    if(index === 0){

        groupingData.startI  = 0;
        groupingData.counter = 1;
        array[0]._groupSize  = 1;

        return true;
    }

    var eq = equalsMethod(array[index], array[index-1]);

    if(eq){
        groupingData.counter++;
        array[groupingData.startI]._groupSize = groupingData.counter;
    }
    else{
        groupingData.startI     = index;
        groupingData.counter    = 1;
        array[index]._groupSize = 1;
    }

    return !eq;
};
```

---

### Problem

For some reason the rendered value for rowspan is always 1.
The attribute is only set for the first td of the first tr of a group, as intended, but the value for it is 1.
If I put a breakpoint inside `isDifferentFromPrev()`, the values seem to be updated correctly. This does not reflect in the html though.

### Solution?

It occured to me that maybe ng-repeat renders each step sequentially, without returning to it. So maybe the `_groupSize` values for the first item of each group do get properly updated, but since they are updated after that item has already been rendered by ng-repeat, the update isn't processed anymore.

I have no idea if this reasoning is correct, nor about how to solve it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: do yourself a favor and preprocess

Comment: @snowman4415 I probably will, but I'm interested in knowing why my approach does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution, even if a bit orthodox, does work:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: 'foo1',
    group: 1
  }, {
    name: 'foo2',
    group: 1
  }, {
    name: 'foo3',
    group: 1
  }, {
    name: 'foo4',
    group: 1
  }, {
    name: 'foobar',
    group: 2
  }, {
    name: 'foobarbar',
    group: 3
  }];

  $scope.itemHasRowspan = function(item) {
    return typeof item === "object" && item.hasOwnProperty("rowspan");
  };

  var groupData = {},
    currentGroup = null,
    addGroup = function(firstItem) {
      currentGroup = firstItem.group;
      groupData[firstItem.group] = {
        "firstItem": firstItem,
        "count": 1
      };
    };

  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, index) {
    if (item.group !== currentGroup) {
      addGroup(item);
    } else {
      groupData[item.group].count++;
    }
  });
  angular.forEach(groupData, function(group, index) {
    group.firstItem["rowspan"] = group.count;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Group</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
          <td ng-if="itemHasRowspan(item)" rowspan="{{ item.rowspan }}" valign="top">
            {{ item.group }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ item.name }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution requires pre-processing, which makes it trivial. I am looking for the reason why my aproach doesn't work.

Comment: Pre-processing is not evil in and by itself, if you combine it with appropriate updating code, given further requirements which are not very clear yet in your exposition.